# PHP, Text files and Arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

I have the following HTML code that I would like to write into PHP. (At the end of this example I have what I have so far.)

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" />
 Please indicate if you us Mathworks MATLAB: <br>
<input type="radio" name="question" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="question" value="no"> No<br>

If yes, please indicate which of these currently purchased toolboxes you use $
form action="action.php" method="post" />
    Please indicate if you us Mathworks MATLAB: <br>
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="no"> No<br>

If yes, please indicate which of these currently purchased toolboxes you use $

<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Control">Control Systems Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Image">Image Processing Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Optimiz">Optimization Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Robust">Robust Control Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="Signal">Signal Processing   Toolbox<br>
 Please enter a comma separated list of toolboxes you would like to use for you$
<input type="text" name="textquestion" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I am looking for a way to put the checkboxes into an array so that the user can check more then one box and that answer is also stored in the text file along with the other answer.

```
<?php
$file = "data.txt";
if(insset($_POST['tool'])){
$tool= $_POST['tool'];
    foreach($tool as $tol=>$value){
    }
} 
 if (isset($_POST['rad']) && value  && ($_POST['question'])) { 
   $fh = fopen($file, 'w+'); 
 $text = $_POST['rad']. ' ' .$value. ' ' .$_POST['question']; 
fwrite($fh,$text); // Write form data to the file
fclose($fh); // Close the file
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you ask if they use MATLAB twice?

Comment: `insset` should be `isset`

Comment: @Barmar maybe they answer differently the second time.

Comment: @Andreas But the code doesn't actually check what answer they gave, it just tests if the parameter is set.

Comment: It was a joke. I meant it as "have you worked with Matlab?", "are you sure you have worked with Matlab?", "Really?".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML code is not good, it should be :

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" />
 Please indicate if you us Mathworks MATLAB: <br>
<input type="radio" name="question" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="question" value="no"> No<br>

If yes, please indicate which of these currently purchased toolboxes you use $
    Please indicate if you us Mathworks MATLAB: <br>
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="no"> No<br>

If yes, please indicate which of these currently purchased toolboxes you use $

<input type="checkbox" name="tool[]" value="Control">Control Systems Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool[]" value="Image">Image Processing Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool[]" value="Optimiz">Optimization Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool[]" value="Robust">Robust Control Toolbox<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tool[]" value="Signal">Signal Processing   Toolbox<br>
 Please enter a comma separated list of toolboxes you would like to use for you$
<input type="text" name="textquestion" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Thus, your checkboxes will all be taken into account.

Then, for create a new array, you use : `$xxx = array();` .
So, in you php file, write :

```
<?php
$file = "data.txt";
if (!empty($_POST['tool'])) {
    $text = implode(',', $_POST['tool']);
}
if (condition) { 
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w+');  
    fwrite($fh,$text); // Write form data to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
}
?>
```

After you change as you see fit.

Comment: Your HTML is not good, either. You can't have `<form>` inside another `<form>`.

Comment: I don't no, is not my HTML, I do not know what he wants to do.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop is just `$text = implode(',', $_POST['tool'])`